# When pressing an arrow key, vim terminal mode is cancelled

Tags: vim

When using vim's terminal mode (access by `:term`) if I put in two double quotes and then press the left button (such as if you were to type in `git commit -m ""` and then go back one character to start the message), the following happens:

1. The terminal is closed.
2. A new line is added above the cursor in the buffer.
3. Insert mode is entered.
4. The character `D` is inserted.

The exact typed sequence is `:term<cr>git commit -m ""<left>`

Why is it that this series of events happens, and how can I prevent it in the future?

Comment: It's not clear why,  but the escape sequence sent by the left arrow key (`^[OD`) isn't being transmitted to the shell in the terminal, but rather being processed by Vim itself.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem (using Vim 8.0 with patches 1-1453) on Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10.  When I try, it just works as expected.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with how your arrow keys are set up in your terminal... Not sure exactly what it is. But try using `<C-b>` as a workaround, it should be equivalent to the left arrow: `:term<cr>git commit -m ""<C-b>`

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that in some terminals the arrow keys are represented with escape key sequences, such as the left arrow represented by `Esc O D`. In my vimrc I had the mapping `tnoremap <esc> <c-w>:q!<cr>` which was meant to close the terminal when I pressed the escape key. But due to how vim interpreted my arrow key sequences, it would close out the terminal when I pressed any of the arrows. I solved this by changing the mapping to `tnoremap <esc><esc> <c-w>:q!<cr>`.

More background can be found on this error here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2216#issuecomment-337566816